# Masks (macros of bits)

Tags: bit, bit-masks

So I'm about to finish my course in university in C programming.
I want to get better at bit operations (such as creating masks) so I'll go to it:

```
#define BIT_I_SET(TYPE,I) ((TYPE)(1) << (I))
#define SET_BIT(NUM,I,TYPE) \
        NUM |= BIT_I_SET(I,TYPE)
```

I am still at  the early stages and learning the syntax at the moment, I have no idea why the compiler says there's error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0109   expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type Project14

full program (yeah it's for synatx only):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SHIFT(I,TYPE) ((TYPE)(1) << (I))
#define NEGATIVE(TYPE) (~(TYPE)(0))
#define BIT_I_SET(TYPE,I) ((TYPE)(1) << (I))
#define BIT_I_CLEAR(I,TYPE) (~((TYPE)(1)<< (I)))
#define MSB_SET(TYPE) ((TYPE)(1) << (sizeof(TYPE)*8-1)
#define SET_BIT(NUM,I,TYPE) \
        NUM |= BIT_I_SET(I,TYPE)
void main()
{
    unsigned char i, j;
    int shift = 3;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    SET_BIT(j, 2, unsigned char);
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(j));
    printf("%d",i);
    system("pause>null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 NUM |= BIT_I_SET(I,TYPE)
```

to

```
NUM |= BIT_I_SET(TYPE, I)
```

You can run just the preprocessor stage of your compiler, which expand the macros
using the command:

```
gcc -E file.c
```